# Dialogflow - Play media response mp3 file from a dynamic URL

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, google-smart-home

I want to play an mp3 file in Dialogflow media response, but the file URL is extracted from an XML file that changes.

This can be solved by adding a script to my server that will update a static file link.

How can I set in Dialogflow in a media response with a dynamic URL fetched from an XML feed?

Answer (score 0):

In the Dialogflow console, I don't think you are able to do that. The console is not setup for dynamic logic. You would want to use a webhook to read the value of your mp3 file and send that as a response.